# ONCLICK LISTVIEW inside a fragment and call another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android studio. I'm creating an app wherein i'd be using a navigation drawer activity.

Perhaps in my drawer there is HTML ,PHP, JAVASCRIPT.
and when I clicked HTML, there is a fragment that shows lists of different topics in an HTML.

So my problem is, how do I assign an onclick in a listview in a fragment to show another fragment?

**Here is my main activity.java file:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
    present.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_html) {
        FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, fragmentHome)
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_js) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_php) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_compiler) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**And here is my FRAGMENTHOME ((also known as fragment for HTML))**

```
package com.webdevkotoreal.coleng.webdevttoolz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


        /**
         * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
         */
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

    public FragmentHome() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false);
        String [] menuHtml = {"Introduction", "HTML Basics", "HTML Comments" };
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.htmlList);

        ArrayAdapter<String> htmlListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            menuHtml
        );
        listView.setAdapter(htmlListAdapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

}
```

I surfed the net but there seems to be no appropriate answer for my question. TIA!